# Tumblr API 401 Not Authorized

Tags: api, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to post content using the Tumblr API. In spite that all my `GET` request work properly, the `POST` ones don't. The code that I use for sign the request is the same I use for my Twitter API client that works as expect. That makes me think that I'm missing something and it's not a bug in the code.

So, I make the following request (I have remove the keys):

```
POST http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/i054.tumblr.com/post/reblog?id=122815544241&reblog_key=FJFgmo68
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MY_CONSUMER_KEY",
oauth_nonce="8a564528bb632870a22d3ca4b5872b1d",
oauth_signature="VePObL9vgiZSuY0yzH3KD%2FhdB7M%3D", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_timestamp="1435942225",
oauth_token="MY_TOKEN",
oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 -- response --
401 Not Authorized
Server:  nginx
Date:  Fri, 03 Jul 2015 16:55:26 GMT
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection:  close
p3p:  CP="Tumblr's privacy policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy"

{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

What's could be wrong? The steps I did were:

1. Create the tumblr app.
2. Authorise my app and take the tokens.

Comment: Are you sure the OAuth token you're including has access to the blog you're trying to reblog to? You can make a call to `/v2/user/info` to see which blogs you have access to.